Identity for squeezing spin coherent state
Let $S_{\pm} := S_x \pm iS_y$ where $S_i$ are the spin operators satisfying the usual commutation relations $[S_i, S_j] = i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk}S_k$.
In Kitagawa & Ueda (1993) it is claimed that
$$e^{itS_z^2}S_+e^{-itS_z^2} = S_+e^{it(2S_z+1)}.$$
Or, more generally
$$e^{itF(S_z)}S_+e^{-itF(S_z)} = S_+e^{itf(S_z)} \tag{1}$$
where
$$f(S_z) = F(S_z+1)-F(S_z)$$
and $F(S_z)$ is a function of $S_z$. Where does the identity $(1)$ come from?

If we use a basis of eigenvectors of $S_z$ the action of the operator in $(1)$ on each basis vector can be easily computed and using either side of $(1)$ gives the same result.

I believe the $\hbar$ in your S commutation relation is superfluous, as per your source, since it has been absorbed in the definition of t. You then obviously have, power-wise,
$$
 F(S_z) S_+ = S_+ F(S_z+1),\qquad  \leadsto \\
e^{it F(S_z)} S_+= S_+ e^{it F(S_z+1)}, $$
$$e^{it F(S_z)} S_+ e^{-it F(S_z)}= S_+ e^{it F(S_z+1)-itF(S_z)} \tag {1}.
$$

$[S_z,S_+] = S_+$
hence, $S_z.S_+ = S_+.(S_z + 1)$
similarly, $(S_z)^2.S_+ = S_z.S_+.(S_z + 1) = S_+.(S_z + 1)(S_z + 1)$
therefore, $(S_z)^n.S_+ = S_z.S_+.(S_z + 1)^{n-1} = S_+.(S_z + 1)^n$
From this relation and expanding $F(S_Z)$ as a taylor series we see that the following relationship holds - $F(S_z).S_+ = S_+.F(S_z + I)$
Hence, $e^{it F(S_z)}.S_+= S_+.e^{it F(S_z+1)}$
